# Is it possible to open a project for development in a Docker container using PyCharm or DataSpell?

Tags: docker, pycharm, containers, dataspell

I would like to develop a Python project located inside a Docker container. The container itself contains the Python/anaconda environment, many python packages and also the project codes.

I am able to use `Visual Studio Code` with a plugin [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) to connect and open the project in the container. And therefore I can create, edit, run codes etc.

**I'm wondering if PyCharm and DataSpell have a similar functionality to allow me to do the same?**

PyCharm has a Docker services, which seems to be mainly for managing Docker services. I have not found any feature that enables me to open a project folder inside a container.

Comment: does PyCharm have the ability to open a project on a remote computer? VSC runs an instance of itself on the remote computer and uses the host VSC to view the screen of the remote and pass the keyboard

Comment: @rioV8 yes....?

Comment: I've figured this out, will post answer asap